# Why the request.user is AnonymousUser in my django-facebook canvas application?

Tags: django, facebook, canvas, django-facebook

I am developing a Facebook canvas application using the frameworks django_facebook.

> I want to save the user data in my local database.

```
@facebook_required(canvas=True)
def home(request,graph):

    facebook = FacebookUserConverter(graph)
    facebook_converter = FacebookUserConverter(graph)
    user_data = facebook_converter.facebook_registration_data(graph.get('me'    ['username'])
    print request.user //AnonymousUser
    facebook_converter.get_and_store_friends(request.user) //This creates error
```

And it gives me error "[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
When I trace back, I found that request.user is AnonymousUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when user is not logged in.

`request.user` by default is a `SimpleLazyObject` which evaluates to the logged in user, if user is logged in. If not, it evaluates to `AnonymousUser` hence the error.

Comment: The Facebook app is only accessed by Facebook logged in user `@facebook_required(canvas=True)`. So, how that be possible, request evaluates to AnonymouseUser??

Comment: They are 2 different things - Facebook login is not the same as django application login. You need to incorporate that logic within your application

Comment: Thank you @karthikr. I changed my Model as per required. And it is working well now.